# package-lock.json not created with npm install

Tags: npm

Am starting a new project with `npm init` but the package-lock.json was not created. I'm also not quite sure what the importance of this file is, cos everything seems to run like normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json)

> package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where
>   npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. It
>   describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent
>   installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of
>   intermediate dependency updates.

Basically you won't see it unless you do a `npm install [module-name]`. Since `npm init` just initializes the project.